# Fetch all feeds from my twitter timeline and show to my Android App

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, feed, android-twitter, twitter-feed

I know it is research topic.
I am not able to find how should I proceed and display some accounts tweet to my android application.

I am reading document by twitter and following with this.

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/tools/console

I am not able to figure out how to use this.

As per my understanding I should use 
`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json` but not able to figure out how to proceed.

If any body know about some good example or anything which make me to move ahead.

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve that you need to download one of the packages available that access the Twitter API using the proper token and key required.

Some of these packages include [tweepy](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy) or [sixohsix](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter). I'm more familiar with tweepy and there's plenty of documentation that would lead you in the right direction, including Youtube videos. They're both available through GitHub.

If you need code specific questions of the two then you need to first give them a try, then ask new questions with the problems you're encountering.